# python loop on list and create one objects for each element in the list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My need seems a bit simple but i still struggle to find the good way to do it.
I have a list of sample names. I want to use a for loop to create one objects for every element of the list.
To be more precise let say that i have the list ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC'] and i want to run a function who read a file and assign the result to an object, so i have a function :

```
def read_10X(filtered_matrix_h5):
    matrix = sc.read_10x_h5(filtered_matrix_h5)
    matrix.var_names_make_unique()
    return matrix
```

if I run the code like :

```
SampleA = read_10X('../path/to/sampleA/file.h5')
```

if get what i want, the SampleA object. But now i want to do it with every element of the list, and just run something like that doesn't work:

```
list_sample = ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC']
for sample in list_sample:
    sample = read_10X(f'../path/to/{sample}/file.h5')
```

I try to use the index by using enumerate() but it doesn't work.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing anything in the list here:

```
list_sample = ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC']
for sample in list_sample:
    sample = read_10X(f'../path/to/{sample}/file.h5')
```

You are only changing the variable `sample`. This is because `sample` is just a variable referring to the value at iteration and you are only changing what the variable points to.

Instead I suggest rebuilding the list:

```
list_sample = ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC']
new_sample = []
for sample in list_sample:
    new_sample.append(read_10X(f'../path/to/{sample}/file.h5'))
```

Or the same thing but using a comprehension

```
list_sample = ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC']
new_sample = [read_10X(f'../path/to/{sample}/file.h5')  for sample in list_sample]
```

Comment: I don't want to create a new list. 
I want to have the same result as if I did :
 sampleA = read_10X(../path/to/sampleA/file.h5)
sampleB = read_10X(../path/to/sampleB/file.h5)
Etc

Answer (score 0):

try the codes

```
list_sample = ['sampleA', 'sampleB','sampleC']
ret = []
for ind, sample in enumerate(list_sample):
    k = read_10X(f'../path/to/{sample}/file.h5')
    ret.append(k)
```

Comment: That will create a new list, my point was more create different objects and get the same result as if I did 

sampleA = read_10X(../path/to/sampleA/file.h5) 
sampleB = read_10X(../path/to/sampleB/file.h5) 
Etc